# How do I "batch reformat" numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel, numbers, format, sum

I am struggling with the following problem:
I have a spreadsheet with one sort of numbers formated as follows:

```
e.g.: displays as 44.0, true value is 44017.08 and what it represents is 44million.
```

the other sort is as follows:

```
e.g.: displays as 5.6, true value is 5634080 and what it represents is 5.6million.
```

the problem which results is, that I have to add them up, obviously returning wrong results using =SUM().
How could I either reformat any of the two to the other's format (adjusting the true values (what is shown to the right of the "fx" top bar) or is there another way to add them up without screwing up (respecting the number formatation during summing)?

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out,

it probably is not the most ideal solution, but it works better than amending all the cells by hand individually. If someone has a more elegant solution (possibliy using a macro/vba as well), pleas share it :)

You simply enter the value by which you want to adjust your data in a seperate cell and copy it. Then you select "Special Paste" below "Paste" in the Edit menu (at least in Excel 2003) and choose how you want to change your numbers.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If one set of values has "true values" in the thousands but should represent millions, the the other set has "true values" in the millions and should represent millions then a simple formula will convert the units

ie if your data was in A1, A2 etc then in  B1
=IF(A1<1000000,A1/1000,A1/1000000)

If by "batch solution" you meant code to replace values directly then pls clarify this. Although you would need to be specific as to what cells should be adjusted insitu and which cells (if any) untouched.

[image]

Comment: hello, thank you very much for taking the time to answer.
Sorry that I have not been entirely clear up fron.
What I ment was, I need some way to actual convert the true value (which you see at the top "fx" bar) into the same format, so I can add them up correctly using =SUM().
The cells to be adjusted are all in one column.

Comment: in that case my formula approach as above is quite simple to use. cheers